# Laravel Update an external database column in migration

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried the following

```
class ...migration

    public function up()
    {
    //
    $connections = \App\AppConnectionsModel::get();
    foreach ($connections as $connection){
        ///set the default configurations
        Config::set('database.connections.inspection.database', $connection->database);
        Config::set('database.connections.inspection.port', $connection->port);
        Config::set('database.connections.inspection.username', $connection->username);
        Config::set('database.connections.inspection.password', $connection->password);
        Config::set('database.connections.inspection.host', $connection->host);


        //then get db and change the column tables
        Schema::table('tbl_users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('password')->default('n/a');

        });


    }

}
```

What am trying to do is to add a column `tbl_users` in an external database table.

What else do i need to add for this to work
?

I have also tried

```
$connections = \App\AppConnectionsModel::get();
    foreach ($connections as $connection){
        //update user
       ...set config as above
        Schema::connection('inspection')->table('tbl_user',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->string('password')->unsigned()->nullable();
        });
    }
```

Comment: after changing DB connection create migration and and then run `php artisan migrate` command in controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database entry in `config/database.php`. For example a sqlite DB I use on a site:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => ['driver'   => 'sqlite',
                 'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
                 'prefix'   => '',],
```

You can give it any name you like, it hasn't have to be *sqlite*. For using another DB apart from the default, use `\DB::connection('yourDBname')->...`

When all DB connections are set in the config, make an array with your connection names and loop them from there.

If you need a Schema for migrations, use `\Schema::setConnection('yourDBname')->create('table_name', function(Blueprint $table) {...}`

Comment: ive tried the above but still the column is not added, Ive updated te question with the try.

Comment: Try with Schema::setConnection('inspection')->table(...)

Comment: Strange. Could it be a database privilege problem? What if you use tinker and enter `\DB::connection('inspection)->table('tbl_user)->find(1);` What does that give you? (edit: all() doesn't exist in this setup, find() does)

Comment: The get not ->all displays the users in tinker

Comment: Ok, one last possibility for your migrations, but this is through a artisan command. If you have 2 DB's that's fine, if you have 40, you won't like it. `php artisan migrate --database=inspection`

Comment: If that works, and your host service allows it, you can run the `shell_exec()` command in a Controller class. In this case `shell_exec('php artisan migrate --database=inspection')` should work.